# WP8 Control not showing

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, grid

I have a WP8 Pivot application and trying to insert a `ProgressBar` and a `TextBlock` within a `Pivot Item` but it just doesn't seem to be showing.

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="Tweets">
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="tweetlist">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                       <!-- I would like to have the Progress bar here -->
                       <!-- I would like to have the textblock here -->

                        <Rectangle Fill="Aqua" Height="50" Width="50" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,7,7,0"
                                   Grid.RowSpan="2">

                        </Rectangle>
                        <Image Height="50" Width="50" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                               VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,7,7,0"
                               Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{Binding Image}">

                        </Image>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateOfTweet}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                                   Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tweet}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black"
                                   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top" />

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <!--                    <TextBlock  Text="Tweet List" Foreground="Black" FontSize="26" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" />-->
            <ListBox
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tweetlist}"
                x:Name="llsTweets" ItemsSource="{Binding Tweets}">
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </phone:PivotItem>
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: Did you set the data to textbox and activate progressbar?

Comment: Might be a z-order problem, try inserting the xaml for the progress bar and the text box after the last text box in your xaml and just before the Grid closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

It's an overlap issue. Don't put more than one control in a cell of a grid and don't use `Grid.RowSpan` if not needed.

Use `stackpanel` or a subgrid to break down a cell to smaller pieces.